# automaticlly changing programming input language when Android Studio is the visual window

Tags: android, android-studio, input-language

When developig in Android studio I often switch windows to Whatsapp, facebook and other none programming related applications / websites. When I am in these none related language I often switch to my native language for typing. When going back to the IDE, I forget that I switched language.

Is there a way to configure that when the visual window is Android studio my input language will always be English automatically? I am using Windows OS if that matters by any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an option in Windows for setting different input language on different apps.

You have to go in Control panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Language > Advanced Settings. Then check ‘Let me set a different input method for each app window’ on ‘Switching input methods’ section.

The procedure is explained here : https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-set-language-on-a-per-app-basis-in-windows-10/